# Move div to top of parent div

Tags: javascript

Originally, I had a parent div on a page, positioned on the first fold, and inside were 150 extra divs, each given an anchor tag name. I could then use a <a ref="#name">, and it would move that div to the top the parent. All was well. However ...

I now have the div halfway down the screen and onto the next "fold". Now when I use "location.href='#name'" in javascript, yes it moves the div to the top of the parent ... but also moves the screen up so that the parent div is at the top of the page, (ie it scrolls the screen so that the lower part of the first fold is at the top of the screen, and the parent div is just below the location bar at the top)

```
<div parent>
    <div child id="jmp_1"><span><div style="font-family:Arial">The Lazy Dog ...</div><br><input type="radio" name="fntChoice" id="fntSel_1"><label for="fntSel_1" >Arial</label></span></div>
    <div child></div>
    <div child></div>
    ...
    ..
    .
</div>
```

Each child div shows the "Lazy dog" phrase written in a font style - about 150 divs in all (so their height differ; I have programatically made the font size change so it fits in a set width)

So if the external program is using (say) font "Cracked Johnnie", I want to change the div bacground colour (done) then move that div to the top of the parent div so it's instantly visible, but without moving the location of the whole page.

I've a feeling it has something to do with **naming** the parent div, and then using something like "document.**show**.location.href='#jump_to'" or "document.getElementById('show').location.href='jump_to' "  I did wonder about "scrollTo" ... but the divs are varing heights, so cannot simply scroll down X*pixels. Maybe 'capture' the position of the window, do the jump, and then reset the page to it's original place, but that's going to look a bit glitchy as the page bounces up and down again.

** I had to enclose it in a <span> as the <br> doesn't work otherwise, and the label appears below the input radio button rather than beside it. Oh, and before anyone tells me, the div code is more complicated. I've simplified  it here so you can still understand what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar dilemma, here is how I eventually solved it:

```
 <div> 
 <a href="jmp0"></a><div>...</div> 
 <a href="jmp1"></a><div>...</div> 
 .. 
 .
 </div>
 
 location.href='#jmp'+x // x is number to jump to
 window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

First a number is added programatically to the href. When the script reaches that line, it loads the page into the browser, and the screen scrolls up so that the jump element is at the top of the screen. The next line of code scrolls the page back down again so that the screen is in its original position (both actions occur so quickly, you cannot see the move up and down ... it just leaves the # part showing in browser window)

One important thing to note: This only works if the screen is normally 'unscrolled', (ie there are no scrollbars used) If your jumped to element is further down the page, it may look odd if it keeps jumping to the top of the screen. In which case, you would need to find your screen co-ordinates BEFORE the jump, and then use scrollTo to reload those co-ordinates again